# Ajax post displaying an inadequate message

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am new to AJAX methods. I want to post some infos that are processes by a php page, call it page.php

In my html page, I have put this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//I have put the function getXMLHttpRequest() on a separate js file
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    var xhr = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        } else {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
    } else {
        alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHTTPRequest...");
        return null;
    }

    return xhr;
}

function request(callback) {
    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "page.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("name=proposition");
}

function postData(Data) {

    alert(Data);

}
</script>

<button onclick="request(postData);">...</button>
```

In page.php, I have a method

```
protected function comment(){
//some code processing the posted infos (that works fine)...

//to debug, I have put a
echo('Hello world');

}
```

The fact is I don't get any 'Hello world' but a huge alert message with all my webpage code displayed.

Anyone has an idea ?

Best,
Newben

Comment: Consider using jQuery for your AJAX, it's less code and much easier ;)

Comment: seriously i don't wan't to offend anyone but i have seen this code with XMLHttpRequests like a million times, i don't expect everyone to use jquery but i expect to research a library that would make things easy for them.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function in page.php, but never calling it.
And remove the protected keyword because it doesn't make sense (you are not making a class)

Try

```
function comment(){
//some code processing the posted infos (that works fine)...

//to debug, I have put a
echo('Hello world');

}

comment();
```

Comment: In fact, to be clearer : the structure of page.php is page.php?page='mypage'&post='post'.So first there is a direction to a mypage.php, and then in mypage.php there is an instanciation of a class. The __construct method takes the post variable to call a method within the class which is called comment(). Does this make sens to you ?

Comment: please post the contents of mypage.php. Seems like a illogical way to do it. I would but all the code in a single file.

Comment: it seems like you're php file is interpreted as plain text, therefore it is displayed in the alert. Did you forget to add the PHP starting tag in either php pages (<?php)

Comment: Excuse but I didn't understand

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12869/discussion-between-edwardmp-and-newben)